# Accessing protected or private property

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, private, protected, private-members

In ActionScript 3 is there a way (**a hack** - maybe through square brackets, maybe through cloning an Object, maybe through prototype, maybe through namespaces, ...) to change a private or protected member of a class?

For example if I have an `IconToast` class delivered by a someLibrary.swc and I know it has a

```
    protected var windowOptions:WindowOptions;
```

Can I change it somehow? I've tried many things, for example:

```
        var errorToast:IconToast = new IconToast();
        errorToast.addButton("Dismiss");
        errorToast.message = "Error when connecting";
        errorToast['windowOptions'].timeout = 10 * 1000;
        errorToast.show();
```

(gives me runtime error *ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property windowOptions not found on IconToast and there is no default value*).

Comment: <protected> means it can be accessed only by classes that extend it. You do not extend it but create a variable instance of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this by extending the base class and giving public access to the private/protected method/property etc.

```
public class MyIconToast extends IconToast
{
    public function getWindowOptions():WindowOptions
    {
        return windowOptions;//here you can access protected (not private though:);
    }
}
```

for private it may not be possible but similar to above solution to some extent it can be done

Best regards

Comment: This is the best way.  The other way would be to modify the ABC before you load the swf.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, There is no way to change its modifier directly( That's why it's defined as public, protected and private, right?). The solution of Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela is OK, but it can be better: use getter/setter to retrieve read/write function.

```
public function set windowOption(option:int):void;

public function get windowOption():int;
```

and the private attributes belong ONLY to their class, so if they're packed into SWC, you can't see any of them:D.